# Bitbucket Cloud will be disabling support for TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 effective 1 December 2018

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

When I push my changes I am seeing this in my TortoiseGit log:

> remote: Bitbucket Cloud will be disabling support for TLSv1 and
> TLSv1.1 effective 1 December 2018.
>
> remote: Please make sure your TLS
> version is updated.
>
> remote: For more info:
> https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-tlsv1-tlsv1-1-2018-12-01

I have gone to the link but it is over my head. Is this something that I need to address and how?

## Git Version

@MrTux This is my Git GUI version:

[image: Git GUI version]

I tried running "Git for Windows" which is on my Start Menu but it just flashes a console screen.

However, I also see this in my Control Panel list of software:

[image: Git Version]

So this is recent.

Comment: I wonder whether it is a generic message for everyone or just for affected people...

Comment: Wait for the Dec. 1st and see if it still works. Btw. if you use ssh then this is a no issue at all.

Comment: Do you use ssh or https?

Comment: @MrTux I use SSH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you use SSH this is just a general hint which BitBucket shows to all its users in order to inform them of a major change which might affect a lot of their users.

If you use an up2date git version (http://gitforwindows.org/), then you are safe.

Btw. this might also affect you if your browser is too old for access bitbucket.org.